# Sybase: "I/O error while reading bcp format-file." while exporting a table to format file

Tags: cmd, io, sybase, bcp

I want to copy the data from a table to a text file or more preferably to an .FD file format. I found this command on the internet,

```
bcp dbname..tablename out -f <file location> -U username -P password -S servername
```

which gives me the I/O error. I am using Sybase database with bcpv15.5 EBF17765, and the table has around 1.4 million data entries. Could anyone please help me?

Please do not give me the link to another similar question on stackoverflow. That is for "IN" operation in SQL. I am looking to do "OUT" operation in Sybase.

Comment: take a look at [bcp command reference](https://help.sap.com/viewer/da6c1d172bef4597a78dc5e81a9bb947/16.0.3.7/en-US/a7e76026bc2b1014ab4fb94d2d25b198.html); you've mixed the `out` and `-f` options; assuming you want to write the results to `<file_location>`, just remove the `-f` flag (`-f` is only required if you're providing a custom format file); as for your comment about a `.FD file format` ... I have no idea what that is

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But now after the command runs it ask for storage type, pre-fix size and stuff like that. So now I have datetime columns also. So for those columns I am giving D as storage type as per this link "http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1570100/doc/html/san1367605076695.html", But in the output file it comes like this "E› ". What do I do about that?

Comment: per the command reference (see link in my previous comment): `-c :
performs the copy operation using the char datatype as the default. This option does not prompt for each field`